# Change Python version in existing Azure function

Tags: python, azure

Based on alert message "Azure Functions support for Python 3.6 is ending on 30 September 2022" we tried to follow steps in [Azure documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python?tabs=application-level#python-version) to upgrade to Python version in existing Azure function. Using Azure CLI to learn the current version, we got an empty string ("linuxFxVersion": ""). Using the command to update the version to 3.9 caused the function to stop working. Fortunately, it worked when the version was set back to 3.6 with the same command.

I could delete the Azure function and all related resources (storage account, application insights) and create it all again but that would mean substantional additional configuration (e.g. for logging). What is the correct approach to change the version?

```sh
az account set --subscription <subscription-id>
az functionapp config show --name <resource-name> --resource-group <resource-group-id>
az functionapp config set --name <resource-name> --resource-group <resource-group-id> --linux-fx-version 'python|3.9'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was not the commands to change Python version. I had old versions of packages in my requirements that were not compatible with Python 3.9. When I updated the version of python to 'PYTHON|3.9' and re-deployed the function with most recent package versions in requirements, the function works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

the commands you provide are the correct one to upadte the python version as explained here: [Changing Python version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python?tabs=asgi%2Cazurecli-linux%2Capplication-level#changing-python-version)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I took the commands from the very link you share as I already stated in my question so this does not help very much.